# multi-recipient PHP email form not sending emails

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, email

I'm trying to get my email form working, but something seems to be hanging up. it's not sending out emails at all!

For reference, this uses Wordpress, and this is the code:

```
<?php
$action=$_REQUEST['action'];
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */
    {
    ?>
    <form  action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
    Your name:<br>
    <input name="username" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
    Department:<br>
          <select id="department" class="form-control-footer">
        <option value="Email_0">Sales</option>
        <option value="Email_1">Support</option>
        <option value="Email_2">Website Feedback</option>
        <option value="Email_3">Other</option>
      </select><br>
    Email Subject<br>
    <input name="emailsubject" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
    Your email:<br>
    <input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
    Your message:<br>
    <textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send email"/>
    </form>

    <?php
    } 
else                /* send the submitted data */
    {
    $name=$_POST['username'];

    if (($department=="Email_0"))
    {
        $mailto=$_POST['example@website.com'];
        }
    if (($department=="Email_1"))
    {
        $mailto=$_POST['example@website.com'];
        }
    if (($department=="Email_2"))
    {
        $mailto=$_POST['example@website.com'];
        }
    else
    {
        $mailto=$_POST['example@website.com'];
        }

    $emailsubject=$_POST['emailsubject'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $message=$_POST['message'];
    if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message==""))
        {
        echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again.";
        }
    else{        
        $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
        $subject="Webform : $emailsubject";
        mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $from);
        echo "Thank you for your email! Your email has been sent, and we will try to respond as soon as we can!";
        }
    }  
?>
```

I've modified the base form to add in departments, which changes the recipient of the contact form. but in doing so, it seems the form no longer sends out those emails at all.

Anyone know what I've done wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? If so, please include them in your question. - Also, why have you wrapped the if sentences in double () ?

Comment: I'm not getting any error messages on the page. Is there somewhere on the website I can access any error logs? Also, I did that because it was the same lower down. I'll try it with single brackets!

Comment: `$mailto=$_POST['example@website.com'];` this doesnt seem right. Did you mean to write `$mailto='example@website.com';`?

Comment: Its better to use `if.. else if..` instead of `if` only

Comment: I honestly have no idea. I'm new-ish to PHP, but it seems everything used in the mail function uses POST, so I assumed the mailto should be the same. The code actually kept blanking out the screen until I added that in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you need to add "name="department"" to the code below

```
<select id="department" name="department" class="form-control-footer">
```

Here you need to change your code as showed below:

```
if (($_POST['department'] == "Email_0"))
{
    $mailto='example@website.com';
}
else if ($_POST['department'] == "Email_1")
{
    $mailto = 'example@website.com';
}
...
```